# how to hide complete tr on the button click through JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have below HTML code

```
<table class="innerGridTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr id="trMain">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOrgReport" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Organisation Reports" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCPUserReport" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="User Reports" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTrainingEventReports" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Training Event Reports" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTokenManagementReport" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Token Management Reports" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogBookReport" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Log Book Reports" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trOrg">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOrganisationReport" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Organisation Report" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOraganisationTotal" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Total Organisation Report" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trCPUser">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCPUser" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="CP User" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCPUserSubTotal" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="CP User Sub Total Report" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnContactPointUserHistory" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="ContactPoint User History Report" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="trTraining">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTrainingCourse" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Training Course" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTrainingCourseTrainer" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Training Course Trainer" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTrainingCourseDelegate" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Training Course Delegate" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTrainingVenue" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Training Course Venue" />
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to hide  on button click. Let me give one example from above code

if you see there are five master buttons in first **tr id="trMain"**. **"btnOrgReport", "btnCPUserReport", "btnTrainingEventReports", "btnTokenManagementReport", "btnLogBookReport"** and below are the child **tr** which will appear according the click on the master buttons.

say if I click **"btnOrgReport"** then it will hide all other child **tr id="trCPUser", id="trTraining"** and will only show **tr id="trOrg"** and if user clicks on **btnCPUserReport** then only **tr id="trCPUser"** will appear and other tr will be hidden.

Please suggest using Jquery.

Thanks,

Best Regards,

Sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOrgReport" CssClass="Button" runat="server" 
Text="Organisation Reports" OnClientClick="hideRow('trOrg');" />

function hideRow(r){
    $("table.innerGridTable tr").hide();
    $("table.innerGridTable tr#"+r).hide();

    return false;
}
```

but you may need another button (outside table maybe?) on clicking which all the rows will be restored:

```
<input id="ShowAll" type="Button" text="SShowAll"/>

$("#ShowAll").click(function(){$("table.innerGridTable tr").show();});
```

Comment: Thanks Dear its not working for me as i need toggle functionality on button

Comment: Hi its showing and then again disappearing, please suggest what to do in this case

Comment: Thanks I have done by putting return false; on OnClientClick="hideRow('trOrg');return false;". Again thanks for your help!